# If a sorcerer rolls on the Wild Magic Surge table and gets a result that says they cast a certain spell, does it require the usual components?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spellcasting, spell-components, wild-magic

Several effects from the [Wild Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic)'s [Wild Magic Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagicSurge-381) table (PHB, p. 104) tell you, the sorcerer, to cast a spell as the result, for example:

> You cast *fireball* as a 3rd-level spell centered on yourself.

The *fireball* spell has verbal, somatic, and material components.

**Does this mean I need to perform the verbal and somatic component and have access to the material component/arcane focus to cast *fireball*?**

What if I don't want to? Is it automatic? Can I remove my component pouch/arcane focus (and only cast material-less spells) to avoid the possibility of accidentally casting *fireball* on myself?

If possible, please elaborate on your answer to clarify the consequences of it requiring or not requiring components.

Comment: Related, or at least helpful reading, and the first may be a duplicate: "[What does it mean “you cast a spell” in terms of a Wild Magic Surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108687)" and "[Wild Magic Surge - What does “You cast …” mean for your spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60555)"

Comment: @Medix2: Indeed, the first question explicitly mentions components as part of it - and the second question touches on it as well.

Comment: This question takes a single sentence out of context from the (admittedly imperfect) Wild Magic class feature.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Is there any other possible context?

Comment: @Vylix When I get to my PHB, I'll either expand on that thought or remove the comment.

Answer (score 12):

## RAW: Yes, it requires components

The rules create exceptions when there are meant to be exceptions. If there is no mention of a specific exception to a general rule, then the general rule applies. In the case of a Wild Magic Surge, you are the caster of the spell, so you must do so with all the components the spell requires.

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/can-a-wild-magic-sorcerer-counterspell-his-own-wild-magic-surge?rq=1) asks if you can *counterspell* your own Wild Magic Surge, and the answers there state that you can. In addition, Jeremy Crawford said in a tweet that [he would allow a Sorcerer to *counterspell* their own Wild Magic Surge](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/803408482602885120), so the RAI seems to be that a *fireball* cast this way can be *counterspelled*.

However, [a spell with no components cannot be the target of *counterspell*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122014/can-i-counterspell-a-subtle-spell-without-material-components) because you cannot perceive the casting. This means, if as the RAI suggests, and that no RAW says otherwise, if you can *counterspell* your own Wild Magic Surge, then it must involve components of some kind.

In the fiction, you can fluff this as you being compelled to cast *fireball* on yourself, rather than a spontaneous explosion happening out of nowhere.

As a result, it does mean that if you are inside an area of silence, as by the *silence* spell, you cannot possibly cast *fireball* on yourself. It also means if you do not have an arcane focus or spell pouch, you cannot cast *fireball* on yourself.

## Rule of Common Sense: No

This is my personal opinion now, but I will back it up somewhat. The [2018 PHB Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) on Wild Magic Surge says:

> If you roll a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Surge table to create a magical effect. If that effect is a spell, it is too wild to be affected by your Metamagic, and if it normally requires concentration, it doesn’t require concentration in this case; the spell lasts for its full duration.

This is a clear signal that the RAI is that a Wild Magic Surge does not have its usual requirements. It is so wild that you cannot even shape it with your Metamagic class feature. If it had the usual V, S, M components, then it would be much less wild than it seems it's meant to be.

The name of the feature itself is **Wild Magic *Surge*** - the image of someone frantically possessed trying to *fireball* themselves is not what comes to mind, but rather an unstable chain reaction happening in the Weave that happens to detonate around the source of that disruption - you.

Therefore, if you want a ruling instead of the RAW, you can say that spells you cast as a result of a Wild Magic Surge does not require any components at all.

Comment: I would argue that you can perceive yourself casting a spell regardless of its requirements.

Comment: @Feathercrown While that is sensible, if we're going with the RAW, then no, you can't. But even if we grant that *counterspell*ing yourself is a gimme, it seems to me that the RAW allows other people to be able to *counterspell* your Wild Magic Surge, too. In addition, it's a *wild surge* of magic - how can you perceive that before it happens, anyway?